# Replacement for S3 bindings that supports Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon has the `S3` package available here:

https://aws.amazon.com/items/134?externalID=134

It's not on PyPI, nor does it have a `setup.py` which is totally lame... But I have to use it because I want to use `django-storages` to have Django use S3 for a `FileField`.

I'm on Python 3.

So I'm using the Python 3 port of `django-storages`. And it offers two ways to store a `FileField` on S3. One is to use `boto`, which is a no-go because it doesn't support Python 3. And the other is to use `storages.backends.s3.S3Storage`, which I now discover requires the aforementioned non-PyPI-hosted `S3` package.

But, that `S3` package doesn't support Python 3. And I'm on Python 3. Does anyone know of a Python 3 port of it? Any other solution comes to mind?

Comment: This ticket seems to have the information you need: https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issue/155/python-3-support

Comment: any progress in here? Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official AWS SDK which supports Python 3. http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforpython/

Comment: Where do you see that it supports Python 3? Are you basing it on the sentence "Boto is being rewritten from the ground up to provide native support in both Python 2 and 3"? You may notice the present progressive tense on that verb.

Comment: I used to work on the AWS SDK team, and know the developers behind it personally. AWS SDK for Python 3.0DP is built on top of botocore, which supports both, and botocore also drives the AWS Unified CLI tools (which also support both). The present progressive tense is because it's a DP instead of a final release.